# Does parallelism always implies concurrency?

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing

As per Arts of Concurrency,
*"A system is said to be concurrent if it can support two or more actions in progress at the same time.
A system is said to be parallel if it can support two or more actions executing simultaneously."*

Today, I was reading about Concurrency and Parallelism.
Most of them discussed Concurrency with respect to single core system only.

I also read that
*"An application can be parallel — but not concurrent, which means that it processes multiple sub-tasks of a task in multi-core CPU at the same time."*

To me, it seems contrasting with the definition and therefore I want to know what exactly is the reason for saying so.

On searching further for examples supporting this statement, the example that emerged out was of **non-preemptive tasks**.
I couldn't understand why two non-preemptive sub-tasks of a task executing on multi-core processor is not called concurrency?
Why do we always associate ***"concurrency"*** with ***"single core system"***?
We are having two actions which are doing progress at same time.

TLDR; My question is
Does parallelism implies concurrency?

If there is parallel processing in a system, can we say there is concurrency as well?

Comment: Concurrency is a programming model. Parallelism is an execution model. In a concurrent program, you describe what parts of the program can be run in parallel. When you run a concurrent program, some of those concurrent parts may run in parallel.